# There is not a/the problem with

Tags: articles

Which article should be used?

> Jeff: There is a problem with a pipe in the toilet. The water has been
> leaking for 2 hours now.
>
> Mark: There is not **a** problem with a pipe in the toilet.
>
> Mark: There is not **the** problem with a pipe in the toilet.

I think THE because the problem has been specified.

Answer (score 9):

"There is **not a/no** problem with the pipe."

Using **the** implies that the problem *does* exist (or did). Mark could say "The problem has been fixed" or "The problem isn't with the pipe - there's a crack in the cistern."

Comment: Mark could also say "There is not any problem with a pipe in the toilet". With a negative existential, you use an indefinite expression like a/any. Compare "Do you have a cigarette?" "No I do not have **a** cigarette."

Comment: But why can't it be "There is not the problem with a pipe"? "The problem" refers to the problem voiced in the first sentence. After all, it doesn't matter what the real problem is in reality, the point is that in the first sentence a problem is mentioned hence in the second sentence one can refer to it as to a specific problem.

Comment: We simply don't say in English "There is not the X" to mean "the X doesn't exist".

Comment: @KateBunting Oddly enough, you *could* say "There is not the slightest hint of a problem"...

Comment: @user1425 But *the problem* doesn't really "refer to the problem voiced in the first sentence", because there is no problem that exists.  Think of it this way: **a** problem means "one of many possible possible problems".  Mark wants to say that there is none of any possible problems, so "not a problem" is correct.

Comment: stangdon, but how do you know that it doesn't exist? It's just Mark's opinion. What if he is wrong and the problem exists? Plus, why does he necessarily have to imply "there is none of any possible problems"? What if he wants to say that only the "voiced problem" doesn't exist?

Comment: Mark's being wrong makes no difference to the grammar of what he says, since he believes that no problem exists. No native English speaker would say "There is not the problem".

Comment: @user1425 It’s arbitrary. We do say, “There is not the slightest problem with the pipe,” but we never say, “\* There is not **the** problem with the pipe.” You just have to get used to it.

Comment: If there is some other problem, but not with the pipe, Mark could say "There is not THAT problem in the toilet", implying there's some other problem.

Comment: @Yukterez - He _could_ conceivably say it, but he would be much more likely to say "The problem isn't with the pipe."

Comment: Even in the situation when a specified problem is being discussed (e.g. "Honey, did you fix the problem with the sink?"), a native speaker would never say "There is not the problem".

Comment: And @Yukterez, a native speaker would never say "There is not _that_ problem in the toilet." A native speaker would say "_That's_ not the problem with the toilet" -- note (i) the word order, and (ii) the use of "with" instead of "in".

Comment: @KateBunting, you said "We simply don't say in English "There is not the X" to mean "the X doesn't exist" Do you say "There is the..." There is the Sun.

Comment: Yes - either to point something out (_'There_ is the shop I told you about.') or to mention its existence ('Is there a restaurant near here?' 'Well, there's a Macdonalds down the road.')

Comment: @KateBunting So, if I want to say that the Sun exists (and not to point at it) I can't say "There is the Sun".

Comment: I can't imagine in what circumstances you would say that. We all know that the Sun exists.

Comment: But it's not the point whether we all know or not all. I approach the matter from the linguistic standpoint. I suppose that there can be circumstances in which it would be fitting to say: "There is the Sun now, but there was a time where there was not the Sun".

Answer (score 4):

> Mark: There is not the problem with a pipe in the toilet.

In this situation this sounds awkward and non-standard to me.  I would go with "a" because the exact problem has not been identified and confirmed to exist.

Using "the" implies a specific problem that the person being spoken to would recognize.  Examples:

- You own a construction company and you have had a recurring issue
  with pipes in the toilet being problematic.  Then, one of your
  employees might say "The project is going well but we've got the
  problem with a pipe in the toilet again."
- The pipe in your bathroom has been leaking and you promised your wife
  you would fix it while she was gone to visit her mother.  When she
  gets back, she might ask "Did you fix the problem with the pipe"

Comment: +1 for mention of it being a recurring problem - that is one valid use for that wording.